# jQuery addClass only to div with class which is really higher

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, padding

The code below causes that all divs with this class get padding including these divs which are not higher than 200, but I need to add padding ONLY to elements, which are really bigger than 200. The rest have to stay without padding. Does anybody know how I can get it?

```js
var n = $('.class');
var height = n.height();
if (height > 200) {
   n.addClass('padding');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.filter` to select just the elements with the height you want:

```
$(".class").filter(function() {
    return $(this).height() > 200;
}).addClass("padding");
```

In your code, `n.height()` just returns the height of the first element selected, it doesn't change what `n` refers to in the `n.addClass()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Use `each()` function to iterate over the `.class` elements and check each height.

Then apply `.padding` class to those who's height is higher that 200px:

```
$('.class').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  if (that.height() > 200) {
     that.addClass('padding');
  }
});
```